# how to recover stepName and exception from selenium results in order to fill Log(LogStatus, StepName, Exception); ExtentReports Selenium with C#

Tags: selenium-webdriver, test-report, logs, extent

how to recover stepName and exception from selenium results in order to fill Log(LogStatus, StepName, Exception) with C#
I'm working with ExtentReports 2.41.0, and I use Selenium tool.

Comment: The easiest solution is to implement a BDD framework, like JBehave or Cucumber, preferably the latter since Extent Reports has a direct interface to Cucumber (A little trickier with JBehave which I use).  Search their documentation for BDD